# Manage the playback speed and position of an MP3

Tags: c++, c, audio, signal-processing, alsa

I'm trying for several months to figure out how it works. I have a program that I'm developing, I have an mp3 file in and out I have the pcm that goes to "alsa" for playback. Using the library mpg123 where the main code is this:

```
while (mpg123_read (mh, buffer, buffer_size, & done) == MPG123_OK)
    sendoutput (dev, buffer, done);
```

Now, my attempts have been based on the use of library avutil/avcodec on the buffer for reducing/increase the number of samples in one second. The result is awful and isn't audibly. In a previous question someone advised me to increase my PC performance but if a simple program like "VLC" can do this on old computers why I can't?

And for the problem of position in the audio file how can I achieve this?

**Edit**
I Add some piece of code to try to explain.

**SampleConversion.c**

```
#define LENGTH_MS 1000      // how many milliseconds of speech to store 0,5s:x=1:44100 x=22050 sample da memorizzare
#define RATE 44100      // the sampling rate (input)
struct AVResampleContext* audio_cntx = 0;
//(LENGTH_MS*RATE*16*CHANNELS)/8000
void inizializeResample(int inRate, int outRate)
{
    audio_cntx = av_resample_init( outRate, //out rate
        inRate, //in rate
        16, //filter length
        10, //phase count
        0, //linear FIR filter
        0.8 ); //cutoff frequency
    assert( audio_cntx && "Failed to create resampling context!");
}
void resample(char dataIn[],char dataOut[],int nsamples)
{
    int samples_consumed;
    int samples_output = av_resample( audio_cntx, //resample context
    (short*)dataOut,    //buffout
    (short*)dataIn,     //buffin
    &samples_consumed,  //&consumed
    nsamples,       //nb_samples
    sizeof(dataOut)/2,//lenout sizeof(out_buffer)/2 (Right?)
    0);//is_last
    assert( samples_output > 0 && "Error calling av_resample()!" );
}

void endResample()
{
    av_resample_close( audio_cntx );    
}
```

My edited play function (**Mpg123.c**)

```
if (isPaused==0 && mpg123_read(mh, buffer, buffer_size, &done) == MPG123_OK)
{   
  int i=0; char * resBuffer=malloc(sizeof(buffer));
  //resBuffer=&buffer[0];
  resample(buffer,resBuffer,44100);
  if((ao_play(dev, (char*)resBuffer, done)==0)){
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Both codes are made by me so I can not ask anybody ever suggested improvements as in the previous question (although I do not know if they are right, sigh)
**Edit2:** Updated with changes

Comment: "if a simple program like "VLC" can do this in old computers why I can't?" have you looked at the source code for VLC ?

Comment: If you don't explain how you're using `avutil/avcodec` how do expect anyone to help? As for repositioning within the audio file, that will depend on the capabilities of the library you're using - if it can't do it, you'll have to read the whole file into memory.

Comment: Avcodec have a specific function for resampling called "av_resample"

Comment: You must not reinitialize `audio_cntx` for each block. And I suspect all your buffer sizes are wrong (are they bytes or samples or frames?).

Comment: Based on the fact that the reproduction start, without resampling, and considering the arguments of the function ao_play are these: `(ao_device * device, **char * output_samples**, uint_32 num_bytes);` I think they are samples. What is the right size of Out Buffer if the input are samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the call to `av_resample`, `samples_consumed` is never read, so any unconsumed frames are skipped.
Furthermore, `nsamples` is the constant value 44100 instead of the actual number of frames read (`done` from `mpg123_read`).
`sizeof(dataOut)` is wrong; it's the size of a pointer.
`is_last` is wrong at the end of the input.

In the play function, `sizeof(buffer)` is likely to be wrong, depending on the definition of `buffer`.